# ionic 2: Can't create resources (icon, splash)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I'm using Mac.
I'm trying to generate icons and splash screens using the command

```
ionic cordova resources ios --icon
```

but I always get this error:

```
[WARN] Error occurred during command execution from a CLI plugin (@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova). Your plugins may be out of date.
✖ Generating platform resources - failed!
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.20.7.16:443
```

icon: icon.png , dimensions 1024x1024.

splash: splash.png , dimensions 2048x2048.

It generates the directory resources/ios/icon contains .png files but when I try to open it I get this alert `The file “icon-40.png” could not be opened because it is empty.`, and when I try to build ios I get this error `Error: Source path does not exist: resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png`
ionic info:

```
global packages:

@ionic/cli-utils : 1.3.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
Ionic CLI        : 3.3.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.1.4
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.3.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.0
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.1.2 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 2.3.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.11.0
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014 
ios-deploy : 1.9.1 
ios-sim    : not installed
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ sudo npm -g remove cordova ionic && sudo npm install cordova ionic
```

It is a known issue that sometimes just updating the package doesn't properly patch to the latest version so it's best to remove and re-add completely.

Then run:

```
$ ionic platform remove ios && ionic platform add ios
```

and:

```
$ ionic resources --icon
```

and finally:

```
$ npm uninstall @ionic/app-scripts && npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

Comment: now the images are exist and i can open them successfully, but when i try to build ios i get the error : Error: Source path does not exist: resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png

Comment: I have updated my answer with more steps. See if `ionic resources --icon` helps.

Comment: Your `@ionic/app-scripts` are outdated. Latest version is `v1.3.7`. You should run `npm uninstall @ionic/app-scripts && npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev`.

Comment: Thank you too much.

Comment: @ĚslǻmÃboĚl-Hǻithęm This may be because your Ionic CLI is trying to use legacy backend and is unable to login to Ionic Pro. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885432/ionic-cant-login-request-post-https-api-ionic-io-login-no-user-found-by-that/45885536#45885536

Answer (score 1):

@maninak, thank you too much.
I solved the first error related to the icon path, the separator in the path in config.xml was backslash "\" but it must be forward slash "/" so the OS was unable to read the path. This error happened because i was working on windows first.
Generating resources error still exists, I couldn't solve it or find any solutions yet.

ionic info after updating:

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-proxy : 1.3.1
@ionic/cli-utils        : 1.4.0
Cordova CLI             : 7.0.1 
Ionic CLI               : 3.4.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
Cordova Platforms               : ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.3.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.11.0
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014 
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 5.0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Splash should be minimum of **2732px by 2732px**. While icon should be, as rightly put **1024px by 1024px**

Then run **ionic cordova resources** to generate both.

It should be noted that the command will still generate some files but not all