# Trying to login into ionic account via c9 terminal dosen't work

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, cloud9

Hey guys im trying to login into my ionic account via c9, but unfortunately it doesn't work, and i added the correct Email and password

it sends back that `No users found by that Email` like this :

> Request: POST https://api.ionic.io/login
>   Response: 404
>   Body: 
>   { link: null,
>     type: 'NotFound',
>     message: 'No user found by that email' }

and im trying to login via c9 typing this

```
ionic login
```

then i type the Email and the password.

ionic version:

> ```
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
> ```

any solutions??

Comment: does with work when trying to log in from your terminal?

Comment: it works from the browser, but from the terminal doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

after i spent many hours and asked alot of people and even opened some new topics in other places, i found out the solution in the end

it is the different between the "old legacy system" and the "ionic Pro".

First check the version :

```
ionic cli -v
```

It should be 3.9.2 at time of writing. If not update it:

```
npm install -g ionic@latest
```

Now you've got the latest CLI you need to tell it to use "pro" not legacy:

```
ionic config set backend pro -g
```

***NOTE*** : it is very important to install it globally not locally.

you can find it here : [Ionic can't login Request: POST https://api.ionic.io/login No user found by that email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885432/ionic-cant-login-request-post-https-api-ionic-io-login-no-user-found-by-that)

thanks to [Martin Joiner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2054138/martin-joiner)